# Firebase snapshot.val() not binding to $scope

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm using FireBase and trying to do some queries, the results are logging in but are not visible in the HTML `$scope`.

```
var shopRef = firebaseDataService.intro;

$scope.shops = [];

var taskRef = shopRef.orderByChild("cat").equalTo("Accomodation");


taskRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    var snapData = snapshot.val();
    console.log(snapData);
    $scope.shops.push(snapData);

});
```

When I use `$scope.$apply()`, I manage to get the data updated to shops, but it's still not passing anything to my directive .

```
    <search-card shops="shops">   </search-card>
    <p> Shops are {{shops}}</p>
```

I got it working somehow with $firebaseArray

```
  $scope.shops = $firebaseArray(taskRef);
```

but I`d still like to know what I'm doing wrong and why it's not working with the snapshot.

Comment: When i use $scope.$apply(), i manage to get the data updated to shops, but its still not updating the scope in my directive . Even with $scope.$watch in the directive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [angularfire docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/beyond-angularfire.html):

```
// read data from the database into a local scope variable
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {

    // Since this event will occur outside Angular's $apply scope, we need to notify Angular
    // each time there is an update. This can be done using $scope.$apply or $timeout. We
    // prefer to use $timeout as it a) does not throw errors and b) ensures all levels of the
    // scope hierarchy are refreshed (necessary for some directives to see the changes)
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.data = snapshot.val();
    });
});
```

It seems that using `$scope.apply()` will not refresh the entire hierarchy (and hence the directive). Try using `$timeout` as prescribed instead

---

That being said, I think you should go with the `$firebaseArray()` option as that strikes me as the most "angular" solution

Comment: with $timeout is working, but it returns an Object, also think that $firebaseArray is a better solution.